# Jquery: form in a popover

Tags: html, jquery

I encountered a problem where html ain't being transmitted to a popover. Instead of containing a form inside it, a popover is being rendered empty.

**Here is js:**

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.with-popover', function() {
  var elem_id = $(this).attr('name')
  $(this).popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true,
    placement: 'top',
    container: 'body',
    content: function(){
      return $("#popover-div" + elem_id).html();
```

**Here is HTML:**

```
    <td id="td-name{{cleaning.id}}" class="text-md-center with-popover" name="{{cleaning.id}}"> {{ cleaning.name }} 
      <div id="popover-div{{cleaning.id}}" style="display: none">
        <form method="post">
        <label for="cleaning_name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="cleaning_name" value="{{ cleaning.name }}"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm update-cleaning"> Update </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </td>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure you want to initialise the popover `$(".with-popover").popover({` *outside* a mouseover event

Comment: I am new to js. If I do the way you suggested and select div like: return $(this).closest('div').html(); it still renders nothing.

Comment: *and select div like: return $(this)* - who mentioned selecting a div? and certainly not like that.  and where have you put that code?   Change `$(document).on('mouseover', '.with-popover', function() {` to `$('.with-popover').each(function() {` but otherwise leave your code as-is (ie remove the `mouseover` event)

Comment: The whole purpose of this is to create a popover with form which HTML code is in a div. My code lives in a js block of a page which extends basic html template. I did what you suggested and it still renders it empty. I can get div's HTML content in variable and it's correct. But can't transmit it to content of a popover.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will run into this issue. You just need to add **sanitize: false** to your popover. Also if you use ajax calls to receive data from your server, use

`$(document).on('mouseover', '.with-popover', function() {`

to toggle popover.